Is there still no supported way to use \sfrac in matplotlib?
I know it's possible to use any available latex feature by editing text.latex.preamble, but this feature isn't official supported by matplotlib. Unfortunately, I find that using usetex=True affects the rendering of some other aspects of my figures (for example, superscripts and subscripts in the legend are now thinner), so I would really like to find a way to use \sfrac without invoking this solution. Is there any other way to use \sfrac in matplotlib?
For example, the following
#adjust latex font parameters
plt.rc('text', usetex=True) #use latex for text
plt.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"] =  " \\usepackage{cmbright}  \\usepackage{xfrac} "
#cmbright is a sans-serif font that is similar to the default latex font
#xfrac allows for slanted fractions in the axis labels
#NOTE: this makes the code take longer to run, but the plot looks better

ax0.set_ylabel(r'$\sfrac{d^{2}\mu(E)}{dE^2}$')


impacts the fonts in the rest of my figure negatively.
